# Is this possible with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have to perform many repetitive actions to make several reports that are not very hard at all, just time consuming. I was wondering if a batch file would be able to replicate what I do or not. Or if there was a way to automate it.

What I do is open a adobe file (.pdf) then I search for a certain term. When it comes to the first one, I page up. Then I extract from page 1 until that page, while deleting those from the file. So my next page will be page 1. I then save those extracted files as (Extract1) or whatever. Then I search for the next term, page up, and extract those files from that new page 1 until then and delete those while saving the extracted ones as (Extract2). And so on and so on. I do it about 20 times.

I am just wondering if it is actually possible to do that using a batch file or what I would need to look into to do it if not.

Comment: Note: batch can't "remote control" GUI programs. If you find a possibility to do it merely on command line (using a CLI program to read/modify pdf files), then the answer probably is yes. Not sure, but GhostScript might do that. An other alternative is "remote controlling" your GUI program (maybe with an AutoIt script)

Comment: Hmmm alright so AutoIt script is something that may work... I will look into it. Thank you.